# Is it possible to install BlackBerry Link && Blend in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, blackberry

BlackBerry couldn't connect without there BlackBerry Link or Blend Software. I am also using "wine" but unable to install. Any appropriate solution?

Comment: Kali https://www.kali.org NEQ Ubuntu. Kali is off topic here per http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic "Questions that you should avoid: … _& other Linux distributions._"  Kali is very different than Ubuntu, both evolved in separate directions from Debian a _long_ time ago. For Kali-specific issues, see http://kali.org/blog & http://forums.kali.org If neither answer your question, Kali's IRC channel is #kali-linux & can be found on irc.freenode.net. . Which release of Ubuntu are you using? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Blackberry%20Sync%20with%20Ubuntu